# Почему объект String не передаётся по ссылке

Tags: java, строки

Доброго времени суток.
В консоль данный код выводит: "**slipstream slip stream**", а не "**slipstream slipstream stream**" как я предполагал. Помогите разобраться, почему **s1** после fix(String s1) не изменила значения на "**slipstream**". Спасибо. [ссылка](https://www.indiabix.com/java-programming/operators-and-assignments/discussion-68)

```
class PassS
{
    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
        PassS p = new PassS();
        p.start();
    }

    void start()
    {
        String s1 = "slip";
        String s2 = fix(s1);
        System.out.println(s1 + " " + s2);
    }

    String fix(String s1)
    {
        s1 = s1 + "stream";
        System.out.print(s1 + " ");
        return "stream";
    }
}
```

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как принятый ^_^

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Читаем [доки](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html).

> Strings are constant; their values cannot be changed after they are
>   created.

Строки иммутабельны; их значение нельзя поменять после создания.

`s1 = s1 + "stream"` в методе `fix` меняет лишь локальную переменную на стеке. Оригинальная строка, определённая в методе `start`, не меняется.

Comment: Насколько я понимаю, иммутабельность в данном вопросе не при чем, а решающее значение имеет передача (ссылки на строку) по значению. В .NET, например, строки тоже иммутабельны, но если бы метод fix был определён как `String fix(ref String s1)`, то есть, с передачей ссылки на строку _по ссылке_, эффект был бы такой, какой ожидал ТС.

Comment: @VladD да, в данном случае вы правы. С другой стороны, на en SO в таких слчаях всегда про иммутабельность говорят https://stackoverflow.com/a/8215448/1991579

Comment: @pavel: Строки вообще не передаются, передаётся ссылка на строку по значению. Если бы строки передавались по ссылке, то изменения этой ссылки (`s1 = ...`) были бы видны снаружи.

Comment: @Suvitruf: Возможно, они говорят так по ошибке. Даже если бы строка и была мутабельна, код в вопросе не делает попыток мутации _самого объекта_! Оператор + не модифицирует никакой из объектов, он создаёт новый объект.

Answer (score 5):

В языке Java **любые** параметры передаются только по значению. Строки исключением не являются.

Вот пример с демонстрацией передачи объекта по значению:

```
class Ideone
{
    String message;     
    Ideone(String message) { this.message = message; } 

    public static void foo (Ideone obj) 
    {
        obj = new Ideone("Если бы я был передан по ссылке, вы бы увидели это сообщение.");
    }

    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        Ideone obj = new Ideone("Но вы увидите вот это, потому что параметры в Java передаются по значению.");
        foo(obj);
        System.out.println(obj.message);
    }
}
```

Запустить пример онлайн можно тут: https://ideone.com/0upGqO

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/68453/discussion-on-answer-by-pavel-mayorov---string----).

Comment: Прокомментируйте это, пожалуйста https://ideone.com/5MmEDH

Comment: @RomanBogdanov я уже отвечал на этот вопрос. Зачем вы пошли на второй круг?

Answer (score 2):

Если вам необходимо изменять строку, используйте [StringBuilder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html).

Answer (score 0):

Все просто! Вы создали переменную `String s1 = "slip";` в методе `start()` и передали ее как параметр в метода `fix(String s1)` и в этот момент в стеке метода создалась новая переменная `s1`, таким образом у нас две переменные (одна вне метода `fix`, другая, локальная в методе `fix`), которые ссылаются на один объект строки. В методе `fix` Вы затем локальной переменной `s1` присвоили ссылку на новый объект строки, в то время как переменная `s1` метода `start()` по-прежнему ссылается на объект строки`"slip"`.

**P.S.**
Всем, кто утверждает, что в Java все параметры передаются по значению. Так оно и есть! Важно понимать, что при передаче объекта передается копия ссылки на объект. Поэтому можно менять свойство объекта, но ни сам объект. Если бы передача была бы по ссылке, то присвоение переменной метода нового объекта отобразилась бы на всех внешних переменных, которые бы стали бы ссылаться на новый объект. Спасибо всем, кто меня поправил!
[Ссылка(см. Passing Reference Data Type Arguments)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/arguments.html)

Comment: `Передача по ссылке тут имела быть место` -- В Java все параметры передаются по значению.

Answer (score 0):

Перечитал все ответы, более полный ответ такой.

В Java все параметры передаются по значению, т.е. даже при передаче переменной ссылочного типа будет создана ее копия, но так как ссылка указывает на один и тот же адрес, то в функции можно менять значение переданного объекта.

Почему это не срабатывает с классом `String`? Потому что этот класс объявлен как `final`, т.е. неизменяемый после создания, поэтому в функции создается его полная копия с данными по другому адресу и все попытки изменить переменную будут лишь плодить ее копии не влияющие на оригинальный объект.

Answer (score -2):

Вы все правильно понимаете в теории ссылочных типов и примитивов. Действительно в данном случае, исходя из общей концепции, ваша переменная должна была изменить свое значение. Вся проблема в том, что класс String объявлен как final. Про подробности использования этого ключевго слова вы можете почитать сами, но суть в том, что не, во -первых, унаследоваться от таких классов нельзя. Во -вторых, в данном случае это самое главное, вы не можете изменить ссылку на созданный объект. Т.е. каждый раз, присваивая одной и той же переменной новое значение на самом деле вы не изменяете старый объект, а создаете новый. Именно это свойство не позволяет Вам видеть передачи значения по ссылке в данном коде, ведь по сути объект типа стринг не изменился, а создался заново. Причины того, что string объявлен как final, достаточно много, основные из них состоят в обеспечении потокобезопасности, скорости работы, соблюдение требований безопасности в целом(это не позволит подменить стринг классом наследником и производить с ним какие-либо манипуляции). В целом же идею ссылочных типов и примитивов , как я уже говорил, вы поняли правильно. Чтобы убедиться в этом , поэксперементируйте с классами, не объявленными как final. Например, в качестве эксперемента, предлагаю взять ArrayList. Дополните свой код таким образом, и увидите. что передача по ссылке действительно отрабатывает...

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

class PassS {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        PassS p = new PassS();
        ArrayList <String> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add("one");
        list.add("two");
        list.add("three");
        System.out.println(list);
        delFirstElement(list);
        System.out.println(list);

        p.start();
    }

    void start() {

        String s1 = "slip";
        String s2 = fix(s1);
        System.out.println(s1 + " " + s2);
    }

    String fix(String s1) {
        s1 = s1 + "stream";
        System.out.println(s1 + " ");
        return "stream";
    }

    static void delFirstElement (ArrayList list){
        list.remove(0);
    }

}
```